# Django celery task keep global state

Tags: django, celery

I am currently developing a Django application based on django-tenants-schema. You don't need to look into the actual code of the module, but the idea is that it has a global setting for the current database connection defining which schema to use for the application tenant, e.g.

```
tenant = tenants_schema.get_tenant()
```

And for setting

```
tenants_schema.set_tenant(xxx)
```

For *some* of the tasks I would like them to remember the current global tenant selected during the instantiation, e.g. in theory:

```
class AbstractTask(Task):
    '''
    Run this method before returning the task future
    '''
    def before_submit(self):
         self.run_args['tenant'] = tenants_schema.get_tenant()

    '''
    This method is run before related .run() task method
    '''
    def before_run(self):
         tenants_schema.set_tenant(self.run_args['tenant'])
```

Is there an elegant way of doing it in celery?

Answer (score 1):

Celery (as of 3.1) has [signals](http://celery.readthedocs.org/en/latest/userguide/signals.html) you can hook into to do this. You can alter the `kwargs` that were passed in, and on the other side, undo your alterations before they're given to the actual task:

```
from celery import shared_task
from celery.signals import before_task_publish, task_prerun, task_postrun
from threading import local

current_tenant = local()

@before_task_publish.connect
def add_tenant_to_task(body=None, **unused):
    body['kwargs']['tenant_middleware.tenant'] = getattr(current_tenant, 'id', None)
    print 'sending tenant: {t}'.format(t=current_tenant.id)


@task_prerun.connect
def extract_tenant_from_task(kwargs=None, **unused):
    tenant_id = kwargs.pop('tenant_middleware.tenant', None)
    current_tenant.id = tenant_id
    print 'current_tenant.id set to {t}'.format(t=tenant_id)


@task_postrun.connect
def cleanup_tenant(**kwargs):
    current_tenant.id = None
    print 'cleaned current_tenant.id'


@shared_task
def get_current_tenant():
    # Here is where you would do work that relied on current_tenant.id being set.
    import time
    time.sleep(1) 
    return current_tenant.id
```

And if you run the task (not showing logging from the worker):

```
In [1]: current_tenant.id = 1234; ct = get_current_tenant.delay(); current_tenant.id = 5678; ct.get()
sending tenant: 1234
Out[1]: 1234

In [2]: current_tenant.id
Out[2]: 5678
```

The signals are not called if no message is sent (when you call the task function directly, without `delay()` or `apply_async()`). If you want to filter on the task name, it is available as `body['task']` in the `before_task_publish` signal handler, and the `task` object itself is available in the `task_prerun` and `task_postrun` handlers.

I am a Celery newbie, so I can't really tell if this is the "blessed" way of doing "middleware"-type stuff in Celery, but I think it will work for me.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you mean here, is before_submit executed before the task is called by a client?

In that case I would rather use a with statement here:

```
from contextlib import contextmanager

@contextmanager
def set_tenant_db(tenant):
    prev_tenant = tenants_schema.get_tenant()
    try:
        tenants_scheme.set_tenant(tenant)
        yield
    finally:
        tenants_schema.set_tenant(prev_tenant)


@app.task
def tenant_task(tenant=None):
    with set_tenant_db(tenant):
        do_actions_here()


tenant_task.delay(tenant=tenants_scheme.get_tenant())
```

You can of course create a base task that does this automatically,
you can apply the context in `Task.__call__` for example, but I'm not sure
if that saves you much if you can just use the with statement explicitly.

Comment: `before_submit()` has to be called during `task.apply_async()`, `task()` or in any other case which starts the task, in the current process or otherwise. As I see it: it is just a filter for the task `*args, **kwargs` that adds a new argument so that it would be passed to the task runner process.

What I need is to save a current global variable _implicitly_ in the base Task class and then restore it _implicitly_ in the process that's going to run the task.